# C# OraOLEDB Stored Procedure OUT Parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, oledb

I'm trying to call such a simple stored procedure by OraOLEDB provider in C#

The procedure has only one OUT parameter. This doesn't work.

DataTable **dt is null** after that part calling `reader.GetSchemaTable()`.

The funny thing is that I can make it works if I put REF CURSOR TYPE as output parameter with other stored procedure. This procedure doesn't have a problem. It can be called in sqlplus. I've read that I don't need to (actually must not) bind `REF CURSOR TYPE` manually.

The problem is how to call a stored procedure which has non-cursor type out parameter by OraOLEDB in C#.

Please give me some advice.

Oracle 11g, Windows 7 64bit
[Link1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e17726/using.htm#OLEDB164)
[Link2](http://www.bowmain.pwp.blueyonder.co.uk/Computing/Oracle/Oracle.html)

```
              try
              {
                  string connStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;User ID=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=//localhost:1521/orcl;OLEDB.NET=1;PLSQLRSet=1;";
                  conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                  conn.Open();

                  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                  cmd.Connection = conn;

                  OleDbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                  param.ParameterName = "O_ENAME";
                  param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                  param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Char;
                  param.Size = 15;

                  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                  cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

                  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                  cmd.CommandText = "{CALL SCOTT.EMPINFO(?)}";

                  OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();             
                  DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();   
              }
```

stored procedure `EMPINFO`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
EMPINFO(O_ENAME OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT ENAME
INTO O_ENAME
FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO=7369;
END;
/
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle, but for SQL server I would use `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then read the value from `param.Value`. Maybe this works too in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much Dirk!! You were right!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.ExecuteReader()` is used only when you return a RefCursor.

For a scalar return values you must use this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string emp = param["O_ENAME"].Value;
```

Maybe this one works also:

```
string emp = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

You cannot use a scalar value for DataTable unless you add the values manually.

Comment: Mark the question as answered if you are so happy.